# "ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table"

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, pl-sql

Estou montando um `select` e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table

```
SELECT A.SEQPESSOA, A.NUMERONF, A.NROEMPRESA, A.SEQPRODUTO, D.SEQCONTRATO, E.PERCDESCONTO, D.SEQCONTRATO, E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO, G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR
FROM MLF_NFITEM A, MLF_NOTAFISCAL B, GE_REDEPESSOA C, MGC_CONTRATO D, MGC_CONTRATODESCONTO E, MAP_PRODUTO F, MGC_CONTRATOFAMILIA G
WHERE A.SEQAUXNOTAFISCAL = B.SEQAUXNOTAFISCAL
AND B.SEQPESSOA = C.SEQPESSOA
AND C.SEQREDE = D.SEQREDE
AND D.SEQCONTRATO = E.SEQCONTRATO
AND F.SEQPRODUTO = A.SEQPRODUTO
AND F.SEQFAMILIA = G.SEQFAMILIA(+)
AND E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO = G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR(+)
```

Eu sei que está dando esse erro pois eu coloquei o (+) em dois campos da tabela G. Sei disso pois se eu retirar um desses (+) o `select` funciona.

Mas eu realmente preciso fazer essas duas associações:

```
AND F.SEQFAMILIA = G.SEQFAMILIA(+)  
AND E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO = G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR(+)
```

E eu realmente preciso que o `select` me traga os registros da tabela da direita mesmo que não exista na tabela da esquerda, mas se eu colocar apenas um (+) em uma das linhas, o `select` não me traz todos os registros que eu quero, por isso preciso realmente dar um jeito de colocar o (+) nas duas linhas.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Parece-me um problema de modelo , pode não existir um Contrato mas existir um Desconto !?

Answer (score 0):

tente fazer o seguinte,

```
    AND F.SEQFAMILIA (+)= G.SEQFAMILIA
AND E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO (+) = G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR
```

basicamente, o sinal de (+) no oracle representa o lado de uma relação que é opcional, utilizado para montar um left join ou right join. Do jeito que estava a sua query, você estava trazendo utilizando a relação ao contrário.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você tentou fazer uma junção referenciando mais de duas tabelas. 
Coloque a condição de junção e a outra condição na cláusula WHERE:

```
SELECT A.SEQPESSOA, A.NUMERONF, A.NROEMPRESA, A.SEQPRODUTO, D.SEQCONTRATO, E.PERCDESCONTO, D.SEQCONTRATO, E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO, G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR
FROM MLF_NFITEM A JOIN MLF_NOTAFISCAL B ON (A.SEQAUXNOTAFISCAL = B.SEQAUXNOTAFISCAL)
JOIN GE_REDEPESSOA C ON (B.SEQPESSOA = C.SEQPESSOA)
JOIN MGC_CONTRATO D ON (C.SEQREDE = D.SEQREDE)
JOIN MGC_CONTRATODESCONTO E ON (D.SEQCONTRATO = E.SEQCONTRATO)
JOIN MAP_PRODUTO F ON (F.SEQPRODUTO = A.SEQPRODUTO)
RIGTH JOIN MGC_CONTRATOFAMILIA G ON (F.SEQFAMILIA = G.SEQFAMILIA)
WHERE E.SEQCONTRATODESCONTO = G.SEQIDENTIFICADOR;
```